# Spanner Spring Data JPA PostgreSQL Dialect PGAdapter In-Process

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-spanner

I'm following along with this documentation https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/use-spring-data-jpa-postgresql and I'm trying to run PGAdapter "in-process".  My PGAdapter class matches the one in this example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pgadapter/tree/postgresql-dialect/samples/java/spring-data-jpa.  When my service starts up I see the following logs.

```
Oct 05, 2023 10:40:40 AM com.google.cloud.spanner.pgadapter.ProxyServer startServer
INFO: Server started on port 9432
```

However, after these additional log entries:

```
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.78]
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2898 ms
o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.15.Final
o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
c.g.cloud.spanner.pgadapter.ProxyServer  : Socket ServerSocket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,localport=9432] stopped
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "spanner-postgres-adapter-proxy-listener" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.expireAfterWrite(java.time.Duration)'
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.pgadapter.ConnectionHandler.<init>(ConnectionHandler.java:112)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.pgadapter.ConnectionHandler.<init>(ConnectionHandler.java:143)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.pgadapter.ProxyServer.createConnectionHandler(ProxyServer.java:315)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.pgadapter.ProxyServer.runServer(ProxyServer.java:287)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.pgadapter.ProxyServer.runTcpServer(ProxyServer.java:247)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.pgadapter.ProxyServer.lambda$doStart$2(ProxyServer.java:143)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.pgadapter.ProxyServer$1.run(ProxyServer.java:159)
```

Here is the entry point of my Spring Boot application.

```
public class MyApplication {

    private static final PGAdapter pgAdapter = new PGAdapter();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void onExit() {
        // Stop PGAdapter when the application is shut down.
        pgAdapter.stopPGAdapter();
    }
}
```

I'm using postgres driver 42.6.0 and I've tried both 0.23.1 and 0.24.0 of google-cloud-spanner-pgadapter but get the same results with each.

I was able to successfully run PGAdapter as a standalone and my service ran successfully.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your pom.xml file? I think this is a dependency compatibility issue.